# git push error: current branch is behind its remote counterpart

Tags: git

I created some file in my system , commited it and pushed it to remote repository. After that i had to delete that commit using command `git reset HEAD~1`.

Now i have modified earlier created files and commited the code again. Now when i am trying to push the code , it failes saying:

`Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart.Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.`

But merging will have to be done manually by seeing what i want to keep/reject and i dont want to do that.

I tried to use `--force` option while pushing but it is also failing with error :

```
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected.
```

Since no-one is using the code from remote repository and i simply want to overwrite files in remote repository.Is there a way to do this.??

Comment: You need to checkout to remote branch and fetch the changes.
So try `git fetch` `git pull` and then push to remote branch.

Comment: Since the server has disabled non-fast-forward updates, it means that you should not change history. So instead of doing `git reset HEAD~1`, you can do a `git revert` on your last commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to use `git pull` and then resolve the conflicts. Thers not much manual work since when there is a conflict git surrounds that part of code with `<<<<<<` and `>>>>>` . And code before `========` is yours and code after that is from remote repository.

After that push the code. you wont get any error.

Its not that hard to resolve conflicts.

By following this way you wont lose any commits also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your question though this is how you merge two commits or delete one of them.

It's not recommanded to rewrite history because others who already pulled your commits are going to have problem on your next push.

If you still want to delete last pushed commit you have to:

`git rebase -i HEAD^^`

You'll see last two commits like:

```
pick 3df324 Add README.md
pick 3245cf bump version
```

Merge two commits:

`bump version` is the last commit. You change the `pick` to `squash` then save+quit the file. You'll see another file opened and you have to leave the text you'll want to use. Next go ahed and `git push -f`.

Delete commit:

If you want to delete a commit simply delete it and save+quit the file.

You can check up [Github docummentation](https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase) for more informations.